# What is measure of angle $BAE$

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ in a square with $|DE|=|CB|$ and measure of angle $CDE$ is $40^{\circ}$.  What is measure of angle $BAE$.  My answer is $25^{\circ}$, but I didn't if it is correct.

[image]

Comment: Can do using coordinates (maybe ugly but it would work).

Answer (score 1):

Angle $CDE = 40$ implies that angle $ADE = 50$. Notice that $|DE| = |CB| = |AD|$ implies triangle $ADE$ is isosceles. Thus, angles $DAE$ and $DEA$ are equal to $\frac{180 - 50}{2} = 65$.Thus, angle $BAE$ equals $90 - 65 = 25$.

Answer (score 1):

$\overline{DE}=\overline{AD}$ so the triangle $\triangle ADE$ is isosceles and the angle $\angle ADE=90-40=50$, hence the angle $\angle DAE={(180-50)\over2}=65$ and the angle $\angle EAB=90-65=25$.